# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not working for test %3cstrong%3ebold %3c/strong%3etest

Tags: c#

System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not working for `test %3cstrong%3ebold %3c/strong%3etest`

Output should be `<strong>bold </strong>test`

Comment: It is hard to understand what your specific problem is here. Can you expand your question, ideally including details of what you're trying to achieve and what's actually happening

Comment: It's not hard at all to know what's being asked here. Stop closing valid questions because you have no idea what it means. People that search for those keywords need exactly what they're searching for, even if it doesn't make sense to you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe you want `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` in this case.

`HtmlDecode` is for things like `&lt;strong&gt;`

Comment: Thank you to your past self--6 years later, people (like me) are making this mistake.  This answer has stood the test of time!

Answer (score 9):

You are mixing up html encoding with url encoding. So it is normal that this does not work. Try using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`

Example for Url encoding:

```
%3cstrong%3ebold%3c/strong%3e
```

Example for HTML encoding:

```html
&lt;strong&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt;
```

Answer (score 4):

[`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) is used for converting [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), e.g.

```
var sample = "&lt;strong&gt;bold &lt;/strong&gt;test";
var result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sample);
// result = "<strong>bold </strong>test"
```

You're looking for [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx), I believe, which surrenders:

```
var sample = "test %3cstrong%3ebold %3c/strong%3etest";
var result = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(sample);
// result = "<strong>bold </strong>test"
```